# attribute error on value for field on serializer django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, model, django-rest-framework, attributeerror

I am receving the following error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `city` on serializer `SearchCitySerializer`
```

my serializers are correct though unless I am clearly missing something.

Here is my model:

```
class SearchCity(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

here is my serializer

```
class SearchCitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('pk','city')
```

*** I tried the serializer without the pk in the field and it still failed

and here it is used in the view:

```
 from serializers import SearchCitySerializer

 def get(self, request, format=None):
        searchcityqueryset = SearchCity.objects.all()
        serializedsearchcity = SearchCitySerializer(searchcityqueryset)

        return Response({
            'searchcity': serializedsearchcity.data,
        })
```

the full error I am getting:

```
File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/suitsandtables/suitsandtablessettingsapp/views.py", line 37, in get
    'searchcity': serializedsearchcity.data,
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 537, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 491, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 462, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `city` on serializer `SearchCitySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'city'.
[28/Feb/2018 02:41:43] "GET /api/dependancy/suitsadmin/settings/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20823
```

THE DATABASE IS CURRENTLY EMPTY AS IN NO DATA IN THE DATABASE AT ALL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
serializedsearchcity = SearchCitySerializer(searchcityqueryset)
```

change to

```
serializedsearchcity = SearchCitySerializer(searchcityqueryset, many=True)
```

To serialize a queryset or list of objects instead of a single object instance, you should pass the `many=True` flag when instantiating the serializer. You can then pass a queryset or list of objects to be serialized.

> [Dealing with multiple objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)